# Change coordinates of view on Titanium

Tags: animation, view, titanium, coordinates

An animation in titanium doesn't change the coordinates of a view. Then what is the best way to change the coordinates (for example top) of a view and then keep track of where it is.

```
var t1 = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
var a1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation();
t1 = t1.translate(0, 10);//Translate on y coordinate
a1.transform = t1;
a1.duration = 800;
view.animate(a1); // Move the view, but the top property keeps the same
```

Thanks, and sorry if it is a silly question!!

Answer (score 0):

`animate()` method does not change any coordinates for reason.

`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` are needed for layout mechanisms.

The easiest way to change the top coordinate is to set it like this.

```
 $.getView().applyProperties({
    top: newTopValue
});
```

And after you set it, it will automatically trigger layout re-calculation